# Iframe is wrong displayed ONLY on FIREFOX

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

Im havin a big problem.
Im programming a website for a company in germany.
Since there are so many sites on the page i took an iframe in my index.html file instead of using a div tag because this would need a lot more time since i need to write the div stuff on every page.

Every Browser like IE,Chrome,Opera and also Safari shows the website like i want it to be shown.
But Firefox shows the iframe part in a small window in the left upper side of the window.
So you cant see any content or even 100x bigger than normally and in a quite small window.

So do I have to change anything in my code or do i need to add something?

The bigger problem is actually that the man who is able to start the server doesnt want to start it for let the website goin online because that doesnt work on firefox. 
He explained the problem to me that way. but my program (mirabyte) shows everything in the right way (ALSO FIREFOX) so what can I do now because I need to let him try every small change i will do. So it would be nice if anyone does know the EXACT answer because he or she already had the problem.

Any ideas? 
Thank you so much

Sasse

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you have the iframe in any sort of container, that container also has the applicable height attribute. Also make sure that the iframe height is applied to both the HTML and the body tags.

Beyond that, we would have to see the part of your code where you're declaring the iframe to say anything more specific.

Comment: <section> 

<iframe id="framebereich" src="welcome.html" name="sectionInhalt" </iframe>

</section>


This is the part where the Iframe is defined.
it is in a section box.
But why does the container need to have the same height attribute? is it also wrong if it has none? 
and why does it work on any other browser then? :(

Comment: Not all rendering engines interpret HTML identically - so it can make a difference, yes. If you say your iframe is 100 pixels, but the section tag is only 50 pixels, then your iframe could be constrained to 50 pixels. I'd try adding CSS to set the height of the iframe and the section.

Comment: allright that sounds good ill have a look if i defined the section part and let you know but thanks so far!

Comment: do you know what "550 Failed to change directory." means? if i try to log in on the server via firefox? Because it seems that you were right but i cant view the entire page because it says that error ive written above...

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes. Basically, it can't find the file/directory you're looking for. Check your slashes?

Comment: allright ill have a look but i think it will work now.
ill tell the man who does that server stuff and if it works then everything is fine. Maybe the error is just on my screen.
But thank you so much for the fast help ill let you know what he said!

Comment: so everything is fine!
thank you so much! 
the 550 error was only my firefox not on his.